# angularjs post file to web api

Tags: vb.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've a angular function for to upload file to web api

```
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
    var file = $scope.file;
    console.log("file: " + file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", uri);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
    $scope.progressVisible = true;
    xhr.send(file);
}

function uploadProgress(evt) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            $scope.progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
        }
    })
}

function uploadComplete(evt) {
    /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
    alert(evt.target.responseText);
}

function uploadFailed(evt) {
    alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
}

function uploadCanceled(evt) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.progressVisible = false;
    })
    alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
}
```

The code is available here http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/4hqVu/

I need a web api controller to manage file post, how can I read it?
Is it possible to use PostValue instead of task async?
Server side I get the file, read content, query a database and return JSON response
Thanks